# Rollback and merge back in specific changesets (after rollback) from same branch

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I've rolled back a branch (call it "trunk") to a specific ChangeSet (call it ChangeSet 1). Now, I need to merge back in only certain ChangeSets (for ex. 3, 5, and 9) that were checked in after ChangeSet 1. These ChangeSets belong to the Trunk.

I was able to successfully merge other ChangeSets that belong to Trunk into branches of the trunk no problem by using the trunk as the source and one of the branches as the target.

However, now I need to merge in the ChangeSets that weren't merged into the branches back into the trunk but I cannot merge from trunk to trunk (VS throws an error `The item <Trunk> is not a branch of <Trunk>`). I do not want the trunk to have the changesets that were merged into the other branches.

I'd like to avoid manually re-doing the changes as there are many.

Any idea how I can do this?

Comment: You are probably going to have to redo everything. Server based source control does not work that way.

Comment: @MrHinsh That's what I ended up having to do but I figured I'd leave the question open if someone answers it for future reference.